# How to read data-sets from a folder specified in Reactive Shiny UI?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have multiple folders containing `.sas7bdat` files. I want to create a shiny app in which I want to provide the folder name from the `selectInput` within `renderUI` function. I have found an answer from which I can get to the part where I can select the folder but now I want to read the data inside the folder and perform analysis on them.

I have tried to use the output generated from the `dir` function but it does not work. Please see my code below.

```
library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Folder Selector"),
      fluidRow(
          sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("select.folder")
          ),

          mainPanel(
            h4("output$dir"),
            verbatimTextOutput("dir"),br()
          )
      )
  )

  server <- function(input, output){

    root <- 'C:/Users/Username/Documents/Mylearnings/data'

    output$select.folder <- renderUI(expr = selectInput(inputId = 'folder.name',
                                                        label = 'Folder Name',
                                                        choices = list.dirs(path = root,
                                                                            full.names = FALSE,
                                                                            recursive = FALSE)))

    dir <- reactive({
          paste0(root,input$folder.name)
    })

    output$dir <- renderPrint(dir())
  }

input.sas <- function(ds)(
      read_sas(str_c(dir,"/",ds,".sas7bdat"))
    )

    a <- input.sas(data_a)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For example if I remove the following part of the code described above, then the result is coming as expected in the `output$dir`,

```
input.sas <- function(ds)(
      read_sas(str_c(dir,"/",ds,".sas7bdat"))
    )

    a <- input.sas(data_a)
```

but I want the output from this to be stored in `dir` and can be passed through `str_c` function.

It gives me the following  error.

```
Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) : 
  object 'data_a' not found
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As your error message states, `data_a` cannot be found. You pass this object to your `input.sas()` function, but `data_a` is not defined anywhere. What are you expecting `data_a` to contain? Also, the content of functions defined in `r` are placed inside `{`, not `(`, so your function should be `input.sas<-function(ds){…}`, not `input.sas<-function(ds)(…)`.

Comment: Oh, yes sorry. I will change that. But as for ````data_a````, it has to be read from a folder ````folder_a````, which I am expecting to select from the ````select.folder```` option and then pass through ````dir```` in  ````input.sas <- function(ds){
      read_sas(str_c(dir,"/",ds,".sas7bdat"))
    }````. Please let me know if there is any way to to so.